# Adding values in a table view cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I have two view controllers. The CardWallet View Controller is my table view. Then the AddCard View Controller is where I input values for a new instance of an object named Card. So far, I am adding those Card instances in an array named myWallet which is in my CardWallet View Controller using a delegate and it works.

What I want is, after clicking the button in my AddCard View Controller, a new table cell will appear in my Card Wallet View, with the name depending on the recently added instance of Card. Below is my code, kindly check why is it that when I'm finished adding a new instance of Card, nothing appears in my table. I've done some research and went through some tutorials, this one is good, http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-and.html, it helped me a lot regarding table view controllers. However, the tutorial doesn't cater my main concern for it's table's values only come from an array with static values.

Thanks!

CardWalletViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CardWalletViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myWallet;

-(void) printArrayContents;
@end
```

CardWalletViewController.m

```
#import "CardWalletViewController.h"
#import "AddCardViewController.h"
#import "Card.h"

@interface CardWalletViewController () <AddCardDelegate>

@end

@implementation CardWalletViewController


@synthesize myWallet = _myWallet;

- (NSMutableArray *) myWallet
{
    if (_myWallet == nil) _myWallet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    return _myWallet;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showAddCardVC"]) {
        AddCardViewController *addCardVC = (AddCardViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        addCardVC.delegate = self;

    }
}

- (void)printArrayContents 
{
    // I want to show the name of each instance of card

    for ( int i = 0; i < self.myWallet.count; i++) {
        Card *cardDummy = [self.myWallet objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Element %i is %@", i,cardDummy.name );
    }

}

- (void)addCardViewController:(AddCardViewController *)sender didCreateCard:(Card *)newCard
{
    // insert a new card to the array

    [self.myWallet addObject:newCard];

    [self printArrayContents];
}





- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
  // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    //this method will return the number of rows to be shown

    return self.myWallet.count;   
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    // Configure the cell...

    //---------- CELL BACKGROUND IMAGE -----------------------------
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LightGrey.png"];
    imageView.image = image;
    cell.backgroundView = imageView;
    [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 


    //this will show the name of the card instances stored in the array

    //

    for ( int i = 0; i < self.myWallet.count; i++) {
        Card *cardDummy = [self.myWallet objectAtIndex:i];
        cell.textLabel.text = cardDummy.name;
    }

    //Arrow 
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

AddCardViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Card.h"

@class AddCardViewController;

@protocol AddCardDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)addCardViewController:(AddCardViewController *)sender
                didCreateCard:(Card *) newCard;

@end


@interface AddCardViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *cardNameTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pinTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pointsTextField;

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <AddCardDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

AddCardViewController.m

```
#import "AddCardViewController.h"
#import "Card.h"
#import "CardWalletViewController.h"

@interface AddCardViewController ()

@end

@implementation AddCardViewController 

@synthesize cardNameTextField = _cardNameTextField;
@synthesize pinTextField = _pinTextField;
@synthesize pointsTextField = _pointsTextField;

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.cardNameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    if ([textField.text length]) {
    [self.cardNameTextField resignFirstResponder];

    [self.pinTextField resignFirstResponder];

    [self.pointsTextField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
    }

    else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.cardNameTextField.delegate = self;
    self.pinTextField.delegate = self;
    self.pointsTextField.delegate = self;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setCardNameTextField:nil];
    [self setPinTextField:nil];
    [self setPointsTextField:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)addCard:(id)sender 
{
    Card *myNewCard = [[Card alloc] init];

    myNewCard.name = self.cardNameTextField.text;

    myNewCard.pin = self.pinTextField.text;

    myNewCard.points = [self.pointsTextField.text intValue];

    // to check if the text fields were filled up by the user
    if ([self.cardNameTextField.text length] && [self.pinTextField.text length] && [self.pointsTextField.text length]) 
    {

        [[self presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        NSLog(@"name saved %@", myNewCard.name);
        NSLog(@"pin saved %@", myNewCard.pin);
        NSLog(@"points saved %i", myNewCard.points);

        [self.delegate addCardViewController:self didCreateCard:myNewCard];

        // to check if there is a delegate
         if (self.delegate){
            NSLog(@"delegate is not nil");
        }

    }
}

@end
```

Card.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Card : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pin;
    @property (nonatomic) int points;

@end
```

Card.m

```
#import "Card.h"

@implementation Card

@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize pin = _pin;
@synthesize points = _points;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should get the obvious question out of the way before anyone starts dwelling too deep into this - do you have some mechanism of reloading the data after you add a new card (e.g. call [`tableView reloadData`] from the `CardWalletViewController`)? I didn't see anything like that, and I've always used this whenever I add something new to a table.*

*If the table contains too much data, you may want to reload only a part of it.

### Update 1: Class Inheritance

Every Objective C class has to inherit from some other class in the hierarchy. By default, unless you say otherwise, all of your custom classes will inherit from NSObject, which is the most generic object out there (equivalent of Object, if you've done Java programming). Changing the parent class is done by simply changing the class after the `:` in your interface declaration. So when you say
`@interface CardWalletViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`
what you are saying is "declare a `CardWallerViewController` custom class that inherits from `UIViewController` and implements the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols" (if you don't know what protocols are, ask).

Now, back to your question. Changing the parent class should be easy now - you just change that `: UIViewController` to `: UITableViewController` and you are done. After you do this, your CardWallerViewController (also, "Waller", really?) will behave like a `UITableView`, not like a generic `UIView`. When doing this, you will also not need to tell it to implement the delegate and dataSource protocols - `UITableViewController` does that by default.

As a final note, when you add new files to your Xcode project, you can tell the program which class you want to inherit from. It defaults to UIView for views, but that's simply because this is the most generic view class. As you begin to use more specific classes (`UITableViewController`, `UIPickerViewController`, `UITableViewCell`, to name a few), changing the parent class off the bat will prove to be more than helpful.

### Update 2: UITableViewCells

That for-loop you've got going there is a (relatively) lot of work you don't need to do. Since your table corresponds directly to your myWallet property, this means that the cell in row N of your table will represent the card at index N of your array. You can use that to your advantage. In the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you tell the program what to do with the cell at the specific indexPath (which is really just section + row for that table). The trick is, this method instantiates the cells one at a time. So instead of doing the for-loop, you can just say (at the end)
`cell.textLabel.text = [self.myWallet objectAtIndex:indextPath.row].name;`

For any cell in row N, this will look at the Nth Card object inside `myWallet` and use its name to set the cell's `textLabel.text`. If it gives you problems, save `[self.myWallet objectAtIndex:indextPath.row]` in some tempCard object, and then do `cell.textLabel.text = tempCard.name`. This is also the proper way to populate cells in a tableView - you only care about one cell at a time, because that's how the method works anyway. Imagine if you had 1,000,000 Cards inside your array - doing the for-loop would force the program to go through the array 1,000,000 times for each cell. Say hello to a 1,000,000,000,000 operations :)

Comment: I didn't used anything like that, can you discuss more how is it done?

Comment: I would add [tableView reloadData] at the end of your `addCardViewController:didCreateCard`. I am no expert, but the way I understand it, telling the table to reload its data does exactly data - reloads everything. So it would call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`for every cell in your table, while adjusting the number of rows.

Comment: Is it this method that you suggest to place the [tableView reloadData] in?

- (void)addCardViewController:(AddCardViewController *)sender didCreateCard:(Card *)newCard
{
    // insert a new card to the array
    
    [self.myWallet addObject:newCard];
        
    [self printArrayContents];
}

Comment: Yea. The way you have it right now, you add a new object to the myWallet array, but you never tell the table that you did. So, because it's lazy, it never updates the table.

I suspect a better way to do it is to use `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]`, but I am not prepared to give you a good advice here without doing some research first.

Comment: I think @Argent has this right.  The table needs to know that the row was added.  No need to do begin/end updates because the tableview is hidden when the delegate method is called.  reload data will suffice.

Comment: @Argent, I've tried adding the [tableView reloadData] inside that method you've stated above. But then, it gives me an error like this:
Unknown receiver 'tableView'. Then the compiler suggests me to use UITableView instead, so I do that, turns out like this [UITableView reloadData].But the reloadData doesn't work, and the error says No known class method for selector 'reloadData'.

Comment: Oh, I see. Make your CardWallerViewController inherit from UITableViewController instead of just UIViewController. Then you wouldn't have to explicitly mention the protocols too. There are other ways, but try this first.

Comment: @Argent 
@ interface CardWalletViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {} - I did this on my CardWalletViewController.h is this one good already? Please correct me if I'm wrong. How do I make my CardWalletViewController inherit from UITableViewController?

Comment: I am going to edit my original answer in a moment - I'd like to explain some basics, and that just doesn't look good in a comment. Stay tuned!

Comment: @Argent Thanks, will wait for those.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info! :) now some things have lightened up. Yet still, regarding the reloadData, it still says the same error as the one I mentioned above :(

Comment: Hmm, that's some black magic. Are you using a NIB file to create the layout of your wallet? I haven't used storyboards, so I don't know what exactly is going on, but it looks like you need a way to access the table from within the wallet. Normally, if you make a class inherit from `UITableViewController`, it's given a `tableView` property by default, and you can use that to access the table and tell it to do stuff. Also, I probably should've asked earlier, but are you using Xcode 4.2?

Comment: Then I am at my limit. You will need some way to access that tableView (it doesn't sound like `self.tableView` will work, but it can't do any harm to try). After you capture that in a variable/property, you can just tell that variable to reloadData. Try putting a breakpoint somewhere so you can look at the wallet object's contents. Worst case scenario, I will create a similar project locally when I have the time and try it out.

Comment: oh yeah, self.tableView works :). I just did [self.tableView reloadData] inside the method we've been discussing. After filling up the values of the instance variables of a new Card, a new cell appears with the label of the Card's name. At last, I have seen progress :)

Comment: Although another problem came up. After adding a new Card, then I wanted to add another Card, the cell label's name becomes changed to that of the latest instance of Card's name. The cells increase in number as I add more, although all of those have the cell names. I'm thinking it's because of the for loop in the method that makes my new cell.

Comment: Maybe. I should hit the bed soon, but check my answer again in a few - I am going to do another quick update and answer whatever other questions you have a good night's sleep.

Comment: No problem - I had a guy help me out big time when I first started using StackOverflow too. I've noticed that people usually need some initial push and then they start figuring most of the things out on their own.

Comment: I wish I could upvote your answer but my reputation's still lacking :|

Comment: Problem, Solved :). Thanks a lot man. The latest update gave me a guide to do this:

Card *cardDummy = [self.myWallet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cardDummy.name;

Comment: Good stuff. Keep on coding - iOS development starts to feel very nice after you go past the initial "wtf is with this IDE, it's black magic..."

Comment: @Argent yo sir! can you check this out? been working for this for two days :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275562/how-to-solve-a-delegate-that-is-still-nil

Comment: It looks like somebody got to your question before me. It looks like you just the delegate setup wrong. The rule of thumb is, whenever you are setting a class' delegate, you do so in the parent's implementation. So, for any tableView and detailedView, you set the detailedView's delegate inside the tableView's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Feel free to email me at scarlet dot argent at gmail dot com, if you need (table-related) advice. I usually respond to emails faster than to Stack posts. Though I lose the rep there... :(

Answer (score 0):

i think u can add the imageview as subview to cell

```
      UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame]; 

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LightGrey.png"];

imageView.image = image;


 [cell addSubview:imageView];  

[[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this one out soon.