# How to solve a delegate that is still nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I am concerned with my 4 view controllers. The first one is the CardWalletViewController which is a table view that is populated by Card Objects that the user has created (the card creation is OK so I won't post the code regarding that). Now, given that this table view is already populated with Card Objects, once the user clicks on a cell, another view controller, named CardDetailsViewController will show up. This will display the current points that the Card has and also the perks. Note that the current points is shown through a UILabel and the perks were a table view's cells. This table view's cell values(perks), are statically typed and are coming from a NSDictionary and then stored in an NSArray (for cell's text display purpose). Now, when I click on a perk, the PerksDetailsViewController will show up. This contains UILabels which show the perk's name and the points it requires. Those UILabels values were coming from the former ViewController. Also, PerksDetailsVC has a button named redeem. Upon clicking that I'll proceed to another view controller, BarCodeViewController, which takes care of the computation.

Now my concern is on how to pass the selected Card, and also the points that corresponds to a selected perk. I've used delegation to do this but then it seems that my delegation object is not being set.

Below is my current code.

CardWalletViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Card.h"

@class CardWalletViewController;

@protocol CardWalletDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)cardWalletViewController: (CardWalletViewController *)sender
                withCurrentCard: (Card *) currentCard;

@end

@interface CardWalletViewController : UITableViewController 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myWallet;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CardWalletDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

CardWalletViewController.m

```
#import "CardWalletViewController.h"
#import "AddCardViewController.h"
#import "Card.h"
#import "CardDetailsViewController.h"

@interface CardWalletViewController ()

@end

@implementation CardWalletViewController

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    Card *cardDummy = [self.myWallet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //myWallet is an Array where the table cell's values come from
    cell.textLabel.text = cardDummy.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cardDummy.points]; 

    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //this method is responsible for showing the details of a selected card

    CardDetailsViewController *details = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cardDetails"];


    Card *selectedCard = [self.myWallet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // I want this selected card to be accessible until the user clicks another card or during end of program.

    details.myPoints = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", selectedCard.points];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];


    [self.delegate cardWalletViewController:self withCurrentCard:selectedCard];

    //checking purposes
    if (!self.delegate) {
        NSLog(@"delegate is nil");
    }
}
```

CardDetailsViewController.m

```
#import "CardDetailsViewController.h"
#import "PerksDetailsViewController.h"
#import "Card.h"

@interface CardDetailsViewController ()

@end

@implementation CardDetailsViewController

@synthesize pointsLabel = _pointsLabel;
@synthesize myPoints  = _myPoints;

@synthesize perks = _perks;
@synthesize datasource = _datasource;
@synthesize datasourcePoints = _datasourcePoints;

-(void)setupArray
{
    self.perks = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [self.perks setObject:@"200" forKey:@"10% Discount"];
    [self.perks setObject:@"100" forKey:@"250Php Off"];

    self.datasource = [self.perks allKeys]; //contains perk's description
    self.datasourcePoints = [self.perks allValues]; //contains perk's required points
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return 2;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

 cell.textLabel.text = [self.datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.datasourcePoints objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PerksDetailsViewController *perksDetails = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailsOfMyPerks"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:perksDetails animated:YES];

    perksDetails.perkDetailsLabel.text = [self.datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    perksDetails.pointsLabel.text = [self.perks objectForKey:perksDetails.perkDetailsLabel.text];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    //show the number of points of the selected Card
    self.pointsLabel.text = self.myPoints;

    [self setupArray];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

PerksDetailsViewController.m

```
#import "PerksDetailsViewController.h"
#import "Card.h"
#import "CardWalletViewController.h"
#import "BarcodeViewController.h"

@interface PerksDetailsViewController ()

@end

@implementation PerksDetailsViewController

@synthesize pointsLabel = _pointsLabel;
@synthesize perkDetailsLabel = _perkDetailsLabel;
@synthesize perkDetailText = _perkDetailText;
@synthesize pointsText = _pointsText;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize pointsRequired = _pointsRequired;


- (IBAction)redeemPressed:(id)sender {
    // get required points of a perk selected
    // cast the NSString value to an NSInteger

     NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
     [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

     self.pointsRequired = [f numberFromString: (self.pointsLabel.text)];

    NSLog(@"points required by the perk %@", self.pointsRequired);

    [self.delegate perksDetailsViewController:self didPassRequiredPoints:self.pointsRequired];

    if (!self.delegate){
        NSLog(@"delegate is nil");
    }
}
```

PerksDetailsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BarcodeViewController.h"

@class PerksDetailsViewController;

@protocol PerksDetailsDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)perksDetailsViewController:(PerksDetailsViewController *)sender
             didPassRequiredPoints: (NSNumber *) requiredPoints;

@end

@interface PerksDetailsViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *perkDetailText;
    NSString *pointsText;
    IBOutlet UILabel *perkDetailsLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *pointsLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *perkDetailsLabel, *pointsLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *perkDetailText, *pointsText;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSNumber *pointsRequired;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <PerksDetailsDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Now this ViewController is the one that implements the two delegate methods

BarCodeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BarcodeViewController : UIViewController 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *myPoints;

@end
```

BarCodeViewController.m

```
  #import "BarcodeViewController.h"
    #import "CardWalletViewController.h"
    #import "Card.h"
    #import "PerksDetailsViewController.h"

    @interface BarcodeViewController () <CardWalletDelegate, PerksDetailsDelegate>

    @end

    @implementation BarcodeViewController

    @synthesize myPoints = _myPoints;
    - (void)perksDetailsViewController:(PerksDetailsViewController *)sender didPassRequiredPoints:(NSNumber *)requiredPoints 
    {
        self.myPoints = requiredPoints;
    }

    - (void)cardWalletViewController:(CardWalletViewController *)sender withCurrentCard:(Card *)currentCard 
    {
        Card *myCurrentCard = currentCard;
        [myCurrentCard.pointsToDeduct addObject:self.myPoints];

        NSLog(@"contents :%@", [myCurrentCard.pointsToDeduct description]);
    }

@end
```

Comment: Where is the code where you set your PerksDetailsViewController's delegate property?

Comment: Will post them in a while, stay tuned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your delegate object property declaration

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <PerksDetailsDelegate> delegate;
```

should be changed from `strong` to `weak`, since your class doesn't own it.

Second, you never set the delegate object for your class. That's the reason why it is `nil`. My guess is that `BarCodeViewController` (your `PerksDetailsDelegate` protocol implementing class) should be an instance variable of the `CardDetailsViewController` and you missed to set it as a delegate of the `perksDetails` object in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Edit.

You should have an instance of `BarCodeViewController` in the `CardDetailsViewController` class (named `bcvController`, for the example code below):

`CardDetailsViewController.m`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PerksDetailsViewController *perksDetails = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailsOfMyPerks"];
    [perksDetails setDelegate:bcvController]; // bcvController should be created before this line
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:perksDetails animated:YES];

    perksDetails.perkDetailsLabel.text = [self.datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    perksDetails.pointsLabel.text = [self.perks objectForKey:perksDetails.perkDetailsLabel.text];
}
```

## Edit 2

BarCodeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CardWalletViewController.h"
#import "Card.h"
#import "PerksDetailsViewController.h"

@interface BarcodeViewController : UIViewController <CardWalletDelegate, PerksDetailsDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *myPoints;

@end
```

BarCodeViewController.m

```
#import "BarcodeViewController.h"

//    @interface BarcodeViewController () 
//
//    @end

@implementation BarcodeViewController

@synthesize myPoints = _myPoints;
- (void)perksDetailsViewController:(PerksDetailsViewController *)sender didPassRequiredPoints:(NSNumber *)requiredPoints 
{
    self.myPoints = requiredPoints;
}

- (void)cardWalletViewController:(CardWalletViewController *)sender withCurrentCard:(Card *)currentCard 
{
    Card *myCurrentCard = currentCard;
    [myCurrentCard.pointsToDeduct addObject:self.myPoints];

    NSLog(@"contents :%@", [myCurrentCard.pointsToDeduct description]);
}

@end
```

## Edit 3

If you want to display a BarcodeViewController, you should use this object's bcvController.

CardDetailsViewController.m

```
#import "CardDetailsViewController.h"
#import "PerksDetailsViewController.h"
#import "Card.h"

@implementation CardDetailsViewController

@synthesize pointsLabel = _pointsLabel;
@synthesize myPoints  = _myPoints;

@synthesize perks = _perks;
@synthesize datasource = _datasource;
@synthesize datasourcePoints = _datasourcePoints;
@synthesize bcvController = _bcvController; // new instance variable

// other functions removed for clarity

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PerksDetailsViewController *perksDetails = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailsOfMyPerks"];
    [perksDetails setDelegate:bcvController];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:perksDetails animated:YES];

    perksDetails.perkDetailsLabel.text = [self.datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    perksDetails.pointsLabel.text = [self.perks objectForKey:perksDetails.perkDetailsLabel.text];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    //show the number of points of the selected Card
    self.pointsLabel.text = self.myPoints;

    [self setupArray];

    [self setBcvController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myBarcodeVC"]]; // use setter to retain object properly

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've already changed it from strong to weak. How do I go about it regarding your second advice? Provide me some sample in your most convenient time.

Comment: I created bcvController by this, BarcodeViewController *bcvController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myBarcodeVC"];

is this one good?

Comment: I just placed it under the creation of perksDetails. But then upon doing that, an error occurred saying "Sending 'BarCodeViewController *_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<PerksDetailsDelegate>'"

Comment: I have this one on my BarCodeViewController.m
@ interface BarcodeViewController () <PerksDetailsDelegate>
@ end
is this one incorrect?

Comment: How exactly are you setting the delegate? Copy the line which gives this error.

Comment: this one gives the yellow warning,     [perksDetails setDelegate:bcvController];
after I've created the bcvController as I commented above.

Comment: As for moving the <PerksDetailsDelegate> from .m to the .h file of BarCodeViewController, it now gives me an error saying "Cannot find protocol declaration for PerksDetailsDelegate"

Comment: Add `#include "PerksDetailsViewController.h"` to `BarCodeViewController.h`

Comment: Ok with this, but then, there still exists the yellow warning regarding the [perksDetails:bcvController];

Comment: Whenever you paste code here, make sure it is correct, please. What does the warning say?

Comment: this one " Sending 'BarCodeViewController *_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<PerksDetailsDelegate>' "

Comment: Are you sure you put the `<PerksDetailsDelegate>` line in your `BarCodeViewController` implementation? `@interface BarcodeViewController <PerksDetailsDelegate>`

Comment: Yep2, just exactly what you suggested sir.

Comment: Is it just a warning? Is everything else functional?

Comment: When the <PerksDetailsDelegate> is in the .m file, it just says that warning and everything works yet my NSLog that checks if the delegate is still nil, says it's still nil. However if it's in the .h file, there is an error saying "Cannot find protocol declaration for PerksDetailsDelegate". I imported the PerksDetailsVC.h wherever I place the <PerksDetailsDelegate>.

Comment: Remove `#import "BarcodeViewController.h"` from `PerksDetailsViewController.h` and keep the the <PerksDetailsDelegate> in the header file.

Comment: Did this yet the warning still appears. The delegate object is not yet set for perksDetails.

Comment: Edit your first post with updated versions of your source files, please.

Comment: Check it out, made it more understandable than previous post

Comment: Yep2 I know, that's why I want to know how. The suggestion you've given still gives me warning. If you have time, may I humbly request to check this one out closely. Been through this almost a day :(

Comment: I tried adding this on my BarCodeViewController.m


`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showBarCode"]) {
        CardWalletViewController *cardWallet = (CardWalletViewController *)segue.sourceViewController;
        
        cardWallet.delegate = self;
        
        PerksDetailsViewController *perksDetails = (PerksDetailsViewController *)segue.sourceViewController;
        
        perksDetails.delegate = self;
    }
}`

yet setting the delegate isn't done.

Comment: Too messy attempt. Try using `CardDetailsViewController.m` to set the delegate the way I said in my original post.

Comment: `BarcodeViewController *barCodeVC;
    [perksDetails setDelegate:barCodeVC];` 
placed this one as you've suggested, yet gave me the same warning mentioned above.

Comment: 1) This doesn't initialize a barcodeviewcontroller object 2) `BarCodeViewController.h` does not implement the delegate protocol

Comment: edited it by using `BarcodeViewController *barCodeVC = [[BarcodeViewController alloc] init];` still, the warning. Regarding point number 2, what do you suggest to do that? Because as of the moment I'm doing the implementation of the delegate protocol in BarcodeViewController.m

Comment: I've done exactly what you've posted and an error appeared pointing to the line `@interface BarcodeViewController : UIViewController <CardWalletDelegate, PerksDetailsDelegate>` saying Cannot find protocol declaration for 'PerksDetailsDelegate'

Comment: Remove `#import "BarcodeViewController.h"` from `PerksDetailsViewController.h`

Comment: So far, no error already. I just want to know how can I check if the delegate object is being set already. Can you check the NSLog I have inside my redeemPressed in PerksDetailsViewController.m if it is a good way of checking. If it's not good, may I humbly request for a way to do it.

Comment: It is an okay way, but initializing the barCodeVC object the way you did might not work. Make the object an instance variable of `CardDetailsViewController`, initialize it in the constructor or somewhere else AND then set it as a delegate.

Comment: Ok thanks :). I didn't quite get what you've suggested, do you mean I make a property? If that is so, what type should it be? an NSObject or a UIViewController?. Can you provide a sample code for that so I can have a guide.

Comment: Ok2 got that, but what is the property type of bcvController then in its declaration in the .h file?

Comment: The same as a regular view controller class member variable. Ordinary (nonatomic, strong) property.

Comment: Ok, done with that. Made use of this to set the property barCodeVC `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *barCodeVC;`
I guess the delegate object is now being set. I've edited the way to check it by using `if (self.delegate){
        NSLog(@"delegate is not nil");
    }`. After clicking the redeemPressed, this NSLog message now appears. Even though it now sets the delegate object, I now receive a warning on line `[perksDetails setDelegate: self.barCodeVC];` saying that " Sending 'UIViewController*' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<PerksDetailsDelegate>'  "

Comment: That's probably because you defined perksDetails as its base class `UIViewController`, change the property to `@property (nonatomic, strong) BarcodeViewController *barCodeVC;` and the warning will go away.

Comment: Hm, I've tried this one yet there still exists the warning. It just changed from "Sending 'UIViewController'...." to "Sending 'BarcodeViewController' ...." :(